# Apache Virtual Host IP address points to another DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, dns, apache2, virtualhost

I installed a VPS on Vultr running Ubuntu 16.04 and using virtual hosts.

There are two domains (abc.com & xyz.com) points to two different dictionary, and now it works fine with Let's Encrypt (SSL).

I can type domain name to access these two websites.

The virtual host file configurations in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` are:

`abc.conf`

```
ServerName abc.com

DocmentRoot /var/www/abc
```

and

`XYZ.conf`

```
ServerName xyz.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz
```

However, this is the question I have now.  Occasionally I found if I type IP address:

`456.456.456.456/xyz`

I thought it will point to the homepage of xyz.com, but it is not.

The webpage is showing and pointing to an error 404 pages (non-SSL) in abc.com

I want to make it to xyz.com, how do I make it right?

Why does it point to another document root?

I checked all `abc.conf` `abc-le-ssl.conf` `xyz.conf` `xyz-le-ssl.conf` configurations in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Comment: This is defined in your VirtualHost, which you did not include here.  If both domain use the same IP address, Apache will not know which one you want when you ask for the IP.  So it will take the first one it finds, from the top of the file down.  So in this case, abc.com.  The easiest way to do that is to have 1 domain == 1 IP address.  This way Apache will know which VirtualHost to use.

Comment: I see, thank you, @Nic3500.  I agree the easiest way is to have 1 domain to 1 IP address (VPS).  That will be much simple.